# Mac can’t read iPhoto

Tags: iphone, ios, mac, import

I tried to import my photos and videos from my iPhone to my Mac and it used to work, but this time it wouldn’t let me and would say “the following file could not be imported. the file is in an unrecognized format” what do I do?

Comment: I think we're going to need more information - what macOS, what iOS at least. iPhoto has been obsolete for several years, so it's not truly surprising if it doesn't behave on a recent macOS or iOS.

Comment: It’s the OS X 10.9.5 and my iPhone is 11.3.1

Comment: So, obsolete OS X but up to date iOS - possibly not a great combination. I don't know if the newer Photos.app will work on 10.9 but that might be the issue - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Photos says 10.10 was the earliest release. It might be time to upgrade that Mac to El Capitan, 10.12 - but wait to see if anyone else has a simpler solution before jumping into it.

Comment: Often this comes up when you have a damaged picture file of some sort. Is it specific about the the file is and can you delete it on the phone?

Comment: Yeah I can delete them on my phone and it says it for recent photos and videos

Answer (score 1):

switch usb port. Or just restart your Mac. It is easier than upgrade.It will work 100 procent. I have no idea why ports are not working after couple of transfer. Can be a memory related problem. or permission to write from transfer threat. God knows.

Comment: This will not fix the issue because iOS 11 uses a new file format for photos and videos, and only macOS High Sierra adds support for the new format.